# Monster Mill v.s. Kitchen Aid Mill attachment

Tags: equipment, grain, mill

We've been looking into getting a grain mill for some time now. I was pretty settled on getting a [monster mill](http://www.monsterbrewinghardware.com/) or some version of it until I saw the [kitchen aid milling attachment](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/-3/-%5BKGM%5D-400565/KGM/). If this would work for milling brewing grains, it would be ideal as I could use the same mill to mill flour since it has variable settings on it. Has anyone ever used the kitchen aid milling attachment to mill grain for brewing?

Comment: I'm still curious to see if anyone has tried the Kitchen Aid milling attachment to mill grain. I ended up buying the budget mill from Northern Brewer. It has great reviews so, I think things look good!

Answer (score 1):

The Kitchen Aid attachment doesn't work well for milling brewing grain according to reports from people who have used them. For one thing, it's made to produce flour, not grist.  That means it mills too fine.  For another, it's not meant for the pounds of grain that you'll have to mill at a time and can overheat.

Answer (score 1):

This mill attachment looks like it might actually be usable for brewing. Most kitchen mills are not, because they will reduce the husk to a fine powder. However, without seeing the internals of this mill I can't say for sure that it would work, and I suspect you won't have fine control over the gap of the rollers.